# Search function in Asp.Core and SQL (using dapper) needs improvment

Tags: c#, sql, api, asp.net-core, dapper

I'm creating a search function within an API that i test in postman. It looks like following:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<GetRequestModelOut>> GetRequest(GetRequestModel model)
{
    var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
    parameters.Add("@CountryID", model.CountryId);
    parameters.Add("@assigneid", model.AssigneId);
    parameters.Add("@RegNumber", model.Regnr);
    parameters.Add("@Vinnr", model.Vinnr);

    if (model.Regnr == String.Empty && model.Vinnr == String.Empty && model.CountryId! >= 0)
    {

        return await _sqlconnection.QueryAsync<GetRequestModelOut>($@" select TOP 5 c.ID as
        RequestID,CountryID,c.createddate as requestDate,RegNumber as regnr,p.Name as produkt, 
        r.WorkshopContactperson as workshop, re.UserID from Contract c

        join Product p on c.ProductID = p.ID
        join Request r on r.ID = r.ID
        join RequestAssigne re on re.UserID = re.UserID
        join Vehicle v on c.VehicleID = v.id ORDER BY requestDate DESC");
    }

    else
    {
        var getReq = await _sqlconnection.QueryAsync<GetRequestModelOut>($@" select c.ID as 
        RequestID,CountryID,c.createddate as requestDate,RegNumber as regnr,p.Name as produkt,
        r.WorkshopContactperson as workshop, re.UserID as UserID from Contract c

        join Product p on c.ProductID = p.ID
        join Request r on r.ID = r.ID
        join Claim cl on cl.ID = cl.ID
        join RequestAssigne re on re.UserID = re.UserID
        join Vehicle v on c.VehicleID = v.id
        where (RegNumber = @RegNumber) OR
        (UserID = @assigneid) OR
        (CountryID = @CountryID) OR
        (Vinnumber = @Vinnr) ORDER BY requestDate DESC", parameters);
        return getReq;
    }

}
```

Here are the models:

```
  public class GetRequestModelOut
    {
        public DateTime RequestDate { get; set; }
        public int RequestID { get; set; }
        public int CountryID { get; set; }
        
        public string RegNr { get; set; }
       
        public string Produkt { get; set; }
      
        public string Workshop { get; set; }
        public string Asignee { get; set; } 
    }

 public class GetRequestModel
    {
        public int CountryId { get; set; } = -1;

        public int AssigneId { get; set; } = -1; 

        [StringLength(10)]
        public string Regnr { get; set; } = "";

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Vinnr { get; set; } = "";

        public DateTime dateFrom { get; set; }

    }
```

my question is: ***Is there a better way to check if the input is empty?*** Currently, I'm doing it with the help of an if statement but it does not always work when i try it in postman.

(i've tried doing the sql query as:)

```
(UserID = @assigneid OR UserID IS NULL) AND
(CountryID = @CountryID OR CountryID IS NULL)
```

But that does not work great either.

**Update [solution]:**

```
  parameters.Add("@RegNumber", model.RegNumber == string.Empty ? null : model.RegNumber);
  parameters.Add("@Vinnumber", model.Vinnumber == string.Empty ? null : model.Vinnumber);
  parameters.Add("@CountryID", model.CountryId == -1 ? (int?)null : model.CountryId);
```

And later in  the sql query do following:

```
select c.ID as RequestID,CountryID,c.createddate as requestDate,RegNumber,
p.Name as produkt, r.WorkshopContactperson as workshop from Contract c
join Product p on c.ProductID = p.ID
join Request r on r.ID = r.ID
join Vehicle v on c.VehicleID = v.id
join Claim cl on cl.ID = cl.ID
where (@RegNumber IS NULL OR RegNumber = @Regnumber)
AND (@Vinnumber IS NULL OR Vinnumber = @Vinnumber)
AND (@CountryID IS NULL OR CountryID = @CountryID)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern will use the parameter value if it is not null and basically ignore the filter if it is null:

```
UserID = ISNULL(@assigneid, UserID) AND
CountryID = ISNULL(@CountryID, CountryID) AND...
```

It won't work for filtering by NULL values though. If users are able to search where something is null you need to get more creative.